# Contributors tab is not showing on own github repo

Tags: github, repository, open-source

In my github repository, contributor tab is not visible, even I check all setting but I am not able to find the solution.

My repo :- [Check](https://github.com/Dev-Sambhav/background_remover)

[Check this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjrxI.png)

The above image is an example of another repo.

I'm hoping to fix my github repo problem because a developer is already working on my github repo and I want to show their work to other people but unfortunately I'm not able to show it because the contributors tab Doesn't appear in my repo.